# Android, prevent button aligned at bottom in relative layout from going up when doing input in edittext

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have created a relative layout with 3 listviews. At top I have a editText field. In the middle there is a scrollview that fills upp all left-over space. At the bottom I have placed a button. The thing is, when I do an input in the editText field, the keyboard shows up and then the button is moved and placed ontop of the keyboard. It seems like the button allways sticks to the bottom of the view that is "left", but I want it to remain at the bottom of the original window.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_course_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/text_view_course_name"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_course_name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_save_course_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="saveCourse"
            android:text="@string/button_save_course" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_course_table"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/ll_save_course_button"
        android:layout_below="@id/ll_name" >

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 7):

Inside your manifest file,

```
        <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" >
```

**NOTE:**
here,I have used HomeActivity,you need to specify the activity name in which you are setting the above layout xml file.

Comment: This answer should be marked as correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="saveCourse"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:text="@string/button_save_course" />
```

or use this

```
 getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```